# SetInterval loop breaking unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have a short piece of code here that I am using to detect when the user stops scrolling. When  it fires the page will switch to the next page. It seems to work once, but when I try to use it again on the next page it breaks and doesn't trigger again. I found out that the timer seems to stop firing after you use it once. I have not managed to find anything related online, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

The JQuery:

```
var scroll = $(window).scroll(function(){
    currentPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(currentPos == 0){
        nextPage();
    }
})

window.setInterval(function(){
    scroll();
}, 500);
```

The code used to switch pages:

```
function nextPage(){
    if(document.getElementById("homePage").style.top == "0px"){
        count = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById(pages[count]).style.top = "-1100px";
    count += 1;
    closeMenu();
}
```

Comment: does nextPage() function refreshes the whole page ??

Comment: it is `window.setInterval`

Comment: @Alok No it does not, it just places the current section so it is out of the viewport

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I have just updated the code, but same issues

Comment: why do you want setInterval in first place?? just register the event once ..

Comment: @NirvikBaruah: Don't update the code in your question unless the code in your question doesn't reflect the original code you were having trouble with, it makes answers you've received in the meantime make little sense. By all means add a note saying "I've tried XYZ" to enhance the question, but changing the code when people have answered isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least a couple of problems there:

1. <s>It's `setInterval` or `window.setInterval`, not `document.setInterval`</s> *(You've since modified the question to use `window.setInterval`.)*
2. Your `scroll` variable doesn't refer to a function, so you can't call it (e.g., `scroll()` is an error). It's a jQuery instance, not a function, as it's the return value of `$(window).scroll(function() { ... })`, which sets up an event handler and returns a jQuery object that wraps around `window`.
3. If `scroll` *were* a function, it wouldn't make sense to call it repeatedly if its purpose is to set up an event handler; you only want to do that once, otherwise you have repeated event handlers interfering with each other.